# Aggregations in a filter only returning values if present in all filtered documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, e-commerce, filtering, faceted-search

For an e-commerce filtering system, aggregations in ElasticSearch have to be calculated over the entire filtered set.

No filters, we get:

```
"filters":{  
    "colour":{  
        "red":{  
            "count":5
        },
        "blue":{  
            "count":4
        }
    },
    "size":{  
        "L":{  
            "count":16
        },
        "M":{  
            "count":15
        }
    }
}
```

Filter on red only, we get:

```
"filters":{  
    "colour":{  
        "red":{  
            "count":5
        },
        "blue":{  
            "count":3
        }
    },
    "size":{  
        "L":{  
            "count":1
        },
        "M":{  
            "count":1
        }
    }
}
```

Filter on blue only, we get:

```
"filters":{  
    "colour":{  
        "blue":{  
            "count":4
        },
        "red":{  
            "count":3
        }
    }
}
```

There is no size for blue, and that's OK. But, if we combine the two:

```
"filters":{  
    "colour":{  
        "red":{  
            "count":5
        },
        "blue":{  
            "count":4
        }
    },
    "size":{  
        "L":{  
            "count":1
        },
        "M":{  
            "count":1
        }
```

Size shouldn't be returned at all, because it doesn't match both colours.

This is what is being sent to ES:

```
{  
    "size":1000,
    "fields":[  
        "id",
        "name",
        "price",
        "colour",
        "size"
    ],
    "query":{  
        "filtered":{  
            "query":{  
                "match_all":{}
            },
            "filter":{  
                "bool":{  
                    "must":[  
                        {  
                            "term":{  
                                "categories":4838
                            }
                        },
                        {  
                            "bool":{  
                                "should":[  
                                    {  
                                        "term":{  
                                            "colour":"blue"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {  
                                        "term":{  
                                            "colour":"red"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs":{  
        "price":{  
            "stats":{  
                "field":"price"
            }
        },
        "discounted":{  
            "terms":{  
                "field":"discounted"
            }
        },
        "stock":{  
            "filter":{  
                "range":{  
                    "stock":{  
                        "gt":0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "colour":{  
            "terms":{  
                "field":"colour"
            }
        },
        "size":{  
            "terms":{  
                "field":"size"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is going wrong? How do you set to aggregate only on the filtered subset where it matches all documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is coherent with the query

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [{
      "term": {
        "categories": 4838
      }
    }, {
      "bool": {
        "should": [{
          "term": {
            "colour": "blue"
          }
        }, {
          "term": {
            "colour": "red"
          }
        }]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

You're asking for items of category 4838 which are blue **OR** red. When you perform an aggregation on size, buckets are created for each sizes in your dataset, which contains both blue and red items of category 4838. That's why you get the size of red items in the result.

> How do you set to aggregate only on the filtered subset where it matches all documents?

I'm not sure to understand your question, since your filtered subset contains both red and blue items. You could use sub-aggregations (https://www.elastic.co/blog/intro-to-aggregations-pt-2-sub-aggregations) to have sizes by color in your result

UPDATE 1:

> If blue and red are selected, and M is only for blue products, but L is for both red and blue, I want to only return L

So you want size to be dependent on color

```
"aggs": {
  "price": {
    "stats": {
      "field": "price"
    }
  },
  "discounted": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "discounted"
    }
  },
  "stock": {
    "filter": {
      "range": {
        "stock": {
          "gt": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "colour": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "colour"
    },
    "aggs": {
      "size": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "size"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use a sub-aggregation to do so (https://www.elastic.co/blog/intro-to-aggregations-pt-2-sub-aggregations)

UPDATE 2:

Final answer after discussion, keep results of OR query, but keep only result of AND query in aggregation

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "colorsizes": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": [{
          "bool": {
            "must": [{
              "term": {
                "size": "red"
              }
            }, {
              "term": {
                "size": "blue"
              }
            }]
          }
        }]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "size": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "size"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, I get why it is happening -- I just don't want it happening like this. If blue and red are selected, and M is only for blue products, but L is for both red and blue, I want to only return L. Is that possible?

Comment: it depends of your mapping. Is color a multi-valued field ? Or do you have denormalized your data ?

Comment: Colour is a multivalued field, yes. A single product can have both a red and a blue variant.

Comment: Thanks for responding -- but that'll show products that are red AND blue, which is not OK :(.

Comment: what result do you expect ? size per color ? size and color ? could you add  the json of the expected result ?

Comment: Expected result is to show all products matching blue OR red, with aggregations that are relevant to all queried products (so size should be omitted, because blue doesn't have any products with size).

Comment: so you want size to be dependent on color ?

Comment: Yes. Show only the size aggregation if all remaining products that are selected in the filtered query have the size aggregation.

Comment: > "show all products matching blue OR red, with aggregations that are relevant to all queried products" actual result is relevant, because you have some blue items and some items of size L. Size is not related to color in your query, if you want to do so, you have to use a sub-aggregation. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77494/discussion-between-juliendangers-and-mave).